# Google API Batch Request with Node

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-api-nodejs-client, node-request

I noticed Google removed batch requests from their Node client recently:

https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/0db674b7d3a04cf65e223f876cf7b3f427025cd4/MIGRATING.md

How might I write a batch request with Node? I'm trying to get the content of emails in Gmail given a set of message IDs.

Here's how Google says I should do it, but I've never made this type of request before:

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/batch

Comment: I think you will have to go through the pain of writing your own request generator or something, so that you can properly generate the request headers and bodies etc. Not a trivial task, unfortunately.:(

Comment: Wow! Alrighty here we go.

Comment: I decided to just use the official Google API Python client for batching and expose it as an API service: https://api.blockspring.com/pkpp1233/8d8aebc5cd4e04f74d432def8f906a4d. Hope that helps others who don't want to write the actual request manually.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've created a module as a stop gap! https://github.com/wapisasa/batchelor

I hope this got to you in time :)