# Batched requests with modern Google APIs Node.js client

Tags: google-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I've recently been trying to refactor some code that takes advantage of the global batch requests feature for the Google APIs that were recently [deprecated](https://developers.googleblog.com/2018/03/discontinuing-support-for-json-rpc-and.html). Currently, we use the npm package [`google-batch`](https://github.com/pradeep-mishra/google-batch), but since it dangerously edits the filesystem and uses the deprecated global endpoint, I'd like to move away from it before the endpoint gets fully removed.

How can I create a batch request using (ideally) only the Node.js client?  I want to use methods already present in the client as much as possible since it natively provides Promise and TypeScript support, which I intend to use.

I've looked into the [Batchelor](https://github.com/wapisasa/Batchelor) package suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28547228/5920903), but it requires you to manually write the HTTP request object instead of using the Node.js client.

Answer (score 0):

[This Github issue discusses the use of batch requests in the new node client.](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/2375)

According to that thread, the new intended method of "batching" (outside of a poorly listed set of endpoints that support it) is to make use of the HTTP/2 feature being shipped with the client- and then just to make your requests all at once it seems.

The reason "Batching" is in quotes is because I do not believe this explanation matches my definition of batching- the client isn't performing the queuing of requests to be executed, but instead managing network traffic better when you execute them yourself.

I'm unsure if I am understanding it correctly, but this HTTP/2 feature doesn't actually batch requests, and requires you to queue things yourself and instead tidys up some TCP overhead. In short, I do not believe that batching itself is possible with the api client alone.

(FWIW, I would have preferred to comment with a link as I'm uncertain I explained this well, but reputation didn't let me)